# Differece in Difference (pooled cross section) for donation data

Tags: modeling, econometrics, difference-in-difference, treatment-effect

I am trying to estimate the effect of a policy that "should" have affected charitable behaviour within the US. To test this, I have data on daily donations for an NGO from all donors (global) from 2017 to end 2020. The policy in particular affected people from the US from march 2020 onwards.

So ideally, I envision setting up a regression at the individual level, and have a treatment variable for people in the US after March 2020.I want to include dummies for specific donation appeals (end of year campaigns), as its important I control for that. Maybe I should include a dummy for US to control for difference in donation amounts between U.S donors vs donors of other nationalities.  Ideally I add month fixed effects, to control for seasonality of giving, and country fixed effects, to control for differences in donation behaviour at the country level (culture etc). I guess I would like to check two things.. did the policy (treatment) affect the amount donated, and also, did it affect the number of donors, so one could think of this as the intensive or extensive margin, so in one I check average donation amount and in the other a dichotomous variable of donated/not donated ' although I am not sure about this last part, whilst also not being quite sure how to control for the campaigns (I have the data and created a dummies, just not 100% how to include them in the diff and diff model)

Comment: Welcome. Please describe in greater detail what this policy is, and whom/what it affects. Is it aimed at NGOs? Which ones?

Comment: Hi Thomas, so the data is individual donations to a conservation NGO, based in the global south, but that is also registred within the EU and USA, so people can use their donations as tax deductible. The data runs from 2017 to end 2020, it includes information on the country of the donor, and if theyr donated in a specific campaign.   The CARE act passed in the US on march 2020 affects the amount of deductions people can make from charitable contributions (incerasing it), and also removed the itemization requirement (expanding the pool of potential donors). This policy only affects U.S Donors.

Comment: So my idea is, run a difference in difference checking US vs EU as control, before/after Care Act. Just by looking at  a simple plot of average mean donations (aggregate level), EU went from average donation 274 dollars before (2019) to 91 (after). US went from 257 average donation (before) to 208 (after).  Average donations look consistent in the previous years, so I might have parallel trends